# NLTK chunked parse tree, save it into a file and loading it with CorpusReader class

Tags: python, nltk, tagged-corpus

Let's say I have a chunked corpus like below, and it is saved in a file called `test.txt`

```
[Rapunzel/NNP] let/VBD down/RP [her/PP$ long/JJ golden/JJ hair/NN]
```

then I can load it with [ChunkedCorpusReader](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html?highlight=chunkedcorpusreader#nltk.corpus.reader.chunked.ChunkedCorpusReader).

```
>>> from nltk.corpus.reader import ChunkedCorpusReader
>>> reader = ChunkedCorpusReader('.','test.txt')
>>> reader.chunked_sents()[0]
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('Rapunzel', 'NNP')]), ('let', 'VBD'), ('down', 'RP'), Tree('NP', [('her', 'PP$'), ('long', 'JJ'), ('golden', 'JJ'), ('hair', 'NN')])])
>>> print(reader.chunked_sents()[0])
(S
  (NP Rapunzel/NNP)
  let/VBD
  down/RP
  (NP her/PP$ long/JJ golden/JJ hair/NN))
```

and I made some change on the Tree object, say, switched the chunk tag from NP to NPP and called `new`.

```
>>> print(new)
(S
  (NPP Rapunzel/NNP)
  let/VBD
  down/RP
  (NPP her/PP$ long/JJ golden/JJ hair/NN))
```

and Now I want to do is save this `new` Tree in a file and load it with ChunkedCorpusReader or any other readers, as I did with `test.txt`. However, I couldn't find a way to save NLTK Tree object in a file, and moreover, read it from a file. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default conversion to string, which `print` gave you, is not bad: It merges words with POS tags, and indents new lines properly. Since `file.write()` doesn't automatically convert to string, you must pass `str(newtree)` to the file's `write` method.

For more control over the appearance of the tree's string representation, use the tree method `pformat()`. Note that `Tree.pformat()` was called `Tree.pprint()` in earlier versions of the nltk; in the latest version, `Tree.pformat()` returns a string while `Tree.pprint()` writes to stdout.

If you want your tree to be delimited by square brackets, add the option `parens="[]"` to `pformat()`.

```
>>> print(new.pformat(parens="[]"))
[S
  [NP Rapunzel/NNP]
  let/VBD
  down/RP
  [NP her/PP$ long/JJ golden/JJ hair/NN]]
```